# How to upload image on server side using javascript and html file control in asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I am using javascript method to upload image using ajax call.
It successfully uploaded on localhost machine but on server machine it throws erro of GDI+.
I uploaded image in the folder of the same project and shows those images.

Here is my way,
HTML:

```
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" onchange="PreviewImageForLabel(this)" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSource1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnFileName1" value="" />
```

Javascript code:

```
function PreviewImageForLabel(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var filerdr = new FileReader();
        filerdr.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('hdnSource1').value = e.target.result; //Generated DataURL
            document.getElementById('hdnFileName1').value = input.value.substring((input.value.lastIndexOf("\\")) + 1)
            document.getElementById('txt_ImageSource1').value = "Images/" + document.getElementById('hdnFileName1').value;

            UploadFileForLabel();
        }
        filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }

}

function UploadFileForLabel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "frmlblExpression.aspx/UploadFile",  //pageName.aspx/MethodName
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'dataURL':'" + document.getElementById('hdnSource1').value + "','fileName':'" + document.getElementById('hdnFileName1').value + "'}", // pass DataURL to code behind
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.d); // Success function
            $("#btnSelectImage").trigger('click');
        },
        error: function (result) {

            alert(result.d); //Error function

        }
    });

}
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string UploadFile(string dataURL, string fileName)
        {
            string directoryPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Bin-debug/Images");
            try
            {

                if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                {

                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);

                }
                Bitmap varBmp = Base64StringToBitmap(dataURL);
                byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dataURL.Split(',')[1].ToString());
                //Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(varBmp);
                //varBmp.Dispose();
                //varBmp = null;

                //newBitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("//Bin-debug/Images/" + fileName));              

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer))
                {
                    using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
                    {
                        bm2.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("//Bin-debug/Images/" + fileName));
                    }
                }

                return "File has been uploaded successfully..!!";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Check the write permission in the uploaded folder in the server.

Comment: All rights has been given to that folder already.